# Help on HP12C SOYD function

Tags: calculation

HP12C SOYD function:

[image: HP12C SOYD function]

I use the soyd function to calculate the percentage variation between two numbers.

```
$1200 -> $1700

Clearly, we have an increase of 41,67%.
```

---

```
But if I type $1700 first and then $1200.

$1700 -> $1200

The HP12C returns -29,41%.
```

Why is that?

I used to think any variation would result the same percentage, I don't understand where -29,41% comes from.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you expect it to yield the same result? 1700/1200-1 = +41.67%, conversely 1200/1700-1 = -29.41%

Comment: The general formula for percent increase or decrease is (new-old)/old, not sure why you think it would be the same number in both directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Percent changes are always relative to the *starting* value.

$1200 is $500 smaller than $1700. $500 is 29.41% of $1700.

Would you expect a change from $2400 to $1200 to be a "100% drop"?

Comment: Although it sounds very obvious I couldn't figure it out logically, but thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

When you go from $1,200 to $1,700 the $500 gain is (500/1200) or a 41.67% gain.

When you go from $1,700 to $1,200 the $500 loss is (500/1700) or a 29.41% loss